# Put all values from input fields into an array and sort them

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-selectors

for my RPG sessions I want to create an Initiative helper, so I have 2 input fields, number+text where number is the modifier to the 
d20 roll and text is the name of the subject (player or npc) -> example of the html (bootstrap components) (I have 6 of these rows so 12 number/text input pairs in total):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Modifier + Player</p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="number" min="-5" step="1" placeholder="0">
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="player1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Modifier + NPC</p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="number" min="-5" step="1" placeholder="0">
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="monster1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I read all the values on click of a button into an object but that is not the optimal base to work with:

```
var subjects = {};
$("#create").click(function() {
    subjects.mod = $("input[type=number]").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
    subjects.name = $("input[type=text]").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
});
```

because now I have ONE Object containing all the numbers and names in an array

```
Object {
    mod=[12], 
    name=[12]
}
```

but I need both properties coupled into 1 object:

```
object1 { 
    "name":"player1", 
    "iniNumber": 17
},
object2 {
    "name":"npc1",
    "iniNumber": 10
},
...
```

I have a function to roll d20 + add the modifier for the final initiative value, but I am too stupid to solve the existing problems...

My current problems:

1. How do I create coupled Number+Name objects from the input fields, which selector/function to use?
2. How do I sort it descending? (I suppose I can do that myself as soon as 1) is corrected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for.

```
// At first there was nothing.
var npcs = [];

// Someone eventually interacted with reality.
$('#create').click(function(){
  // For every row in now... (You should add another class because you only want npc rows)
  $('.row').each(function(i, $row){
      // Create object from inputs of a specific row from this dimension.
      var newNpc = {
        name: $('input[type=text]', $row).val(),
        iniNumber: $('input[type=number]', $row).val()
      };

      // Add object to array to fill our insecurities.
      npcs.push(newNpc);
  });
});
```

Comment: works as expected, thanks good sir! I'd upvote but rep is missing ;)